# KNN - How do I speed up?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, knn

I have a df of ~ 65 features, 450k observations, and unbalanced categorical response variable Y (~5% true, 2 states).  This has been split via train_test_split into  {Xtrain, ytrain} (10%) and {Xtest, ytest} (90%).

I am attempting to tune N_neighbors hyperparamater for classifier KNN.  I was using gridsearchCV with StratifiedKfoldCV but abandoned the attempt because the loop was taking so long (over 12 hrs, for 25 values of N_Neighbors, 3 fold CV).

I have isolated the cause to the predict_proba method. Here's the excerpt from the current code I am running, with the identified code highlighted:

```
[In]
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score, confusion_matrix

clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
Xtrain_Scaled = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(Xtrain)
Xtest_Scaled = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(Xtest)

clf.fit(Xtrain_Scaled, ytrain)
...

**y_probas_KNN = clf.predict_proba(Xtest_Scaled)[:,1]**
```

Currently, the notebook has been running for over 2 hours on this line (isolated now in a separate cell).   This is not intuitive, as the predict_proba method for other classifiers (logistic regression, DecisionTreeClassifier) doesn't take anywhere close to this length of time.

UPDATE 11AUG15 - 
There is clearly something strange gong on:

Running predict_proba on 100k observations in Xtest (e.g., Xtest[;1000,] takes way longer than predict_predict proba on Xtrain (45k observations).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There are ulternative implementations of KNN that include kmcuda e.g., based on GPU, 10x faster.

Answer (score 1):

450K rows is generally a bit large for training a predictive model in Scikit-learn. You will probably still good results if you undersample your non-responders (keep all the responders) to bring your dataset under 100K rows.

Comment: thanks for your response.   Maybe I wasn't clear in the size of Xtrain, Xtest.   Xtrain is 10% of 450k ~ 45k.    The code executes fine up until the point where it attempts to calculate probabilities for Xtest (nb, Xtrain, Xtest are scaled).    What is best strategy for under sampling?